# Stream object passed in restful webservices and consumed via resttemplate

Tags: java, web-services, stream, resttemplate

I have a controller class which exposes a method and returns object as Stream(java 8)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/book/class/{class}"},method =     RequestMethod.GET)
 @ApiOperation(response = Book.class, responseContainer="List", value =     "Get all books of a class")
 public Stream<Book> getBooksForAllClass(@PathVariable("class") String class) {
    return myService.getBooksForClass().map(book -> Book.createBuilder().withBook();
   }
```

The reset service consumer client side i need to get the Stream object and store it into a list. Hence,

```
 List<Book> books = Lists.newArrayList();
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String resourceUri = String.format("%s/%s", serviceUrl, "class_a");
 Book[] arrayOfBooks = restTemplate.getForObject(resourceUri, Book[].class);
 books.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayOfBooks));
```

This does not seem to work. Is there any way to consume the stream object via resttemplate ?

Comment: take a look at javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between type in your rest controller and client.  So you have `public Stream<Book> getBooksForAllClass` and `restTemplate.getForObject(resourceUri, Book[].class);`; `Stream<Book>` vs `Book[]`.  If you want to get an array of books in your client, you have to convert your stream to an array first. `stream().toArray(Book[]::new)`.

And you probably should avoid stream serialization, because it is  is a single-use chain of operations and never meant to be persistent. If you will apply terminal operation to your stream, you won't be able to reuse the stream again. Using `List<Book>` or `Book[]` will be better choice in this case.